# How to separate the model object for view and domain entity object for database in Spring Roo?

Tags: spring-roo

Often, I can not use the @RooMongoEntity entity class as a view model directly, for example:

```
// domain entity
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooMongoEntity
public class CouponItem {

    @NotNull
    private String contentId;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    private String detailUrl;

    private String detailPage;

    @RooUploadedFile(contentType = "image/jpeg")
    @Lob
    private byte[] picture;
```

}

but I need another bean for view layer:

```
// bean for view layer
public class CouponDoItem {
    private String id;
    private String contentId;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String pictureUrl;
    private String detailUrl;
}
```

so, How to generate the view pages (list.jspx, create.jspx, show.jspx, update.jspx) for CouponDoItem bean?

Answer (score 0):

Create the web layer for *CouponItem* entity and customize it to use *CouponDoItem*.

You can customize it by pushing-in generated Spring MVC controller methods for the *CouponItem* entity and modifying them as needed.